# Titanium can't find my Android Nexus device

Tags: android, macos, titanium, appcelerator

Hi I'm trying to compile a Titanium Android app directly on my Nexus 7 (2013, SDK 4.3) device but I can't see any 'Titanium on Android Device' option in the Run Configurations.

My device is in Developer mode, connected to the USB, detected by Android File Transfer (Mac OS X 10.9, Titanium 3.1.4), detected by adb...

I tried to restart adb, restart Titanium, plug and unplug the device, but I still cannot see the option.

I also tested all this with Titanium 3.1.3, with no success.

I have no clue of what's happening :/ any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was a bit confusing but I finally found such option inside a Project Explorer menu...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may sound stupid, but my friend had similar problems with his Nexus and he changed the USB slot to which he plugged his device and it worked.

Comment: It didn't worked... see my answer, the option was 'hidden' under a project explorer button :/  thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different cable. Most cables are only able to load the device, somehow. Not every micro-USB-cable is capable of sending data, correctly.

Again a reason why I don´t like to work in the android environment. No one checks whether software and hardware is working the way it´s supposed to. That´s why I love Apples restrictive "closed" system. No 1000 viruses and other crap.